# apache redirect to remove a subfolder from the url

Tags: apache, redirect

I have issues redirecting a specific url within the same domain

Example, I want to redirect

```
http://example.tld/folder/*
```

to

```
http://example.tld/*
```

where * is a wildcard

Answer (score 0):

Basically you will need this type of code in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/folder/ http://domain.tld/? [R=301,L]
```

This should redirect your current url http://domain.tld/folder to http:/domain.tld/

Or:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Please try and see which one works best for you